# Extrinsic Brownian Motion on Manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

I recently saw the following characterization of Brownian motion on an embedded manifold:
Let  $M$ be a manifold embedded in $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Consider some point $p\in M$, for $\vec{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ let $P_i(\vec{x})$ be the projection of the $i$th coordinate of $\vec{x}$ onto $T_p M$.  Now, Brownian motion on $M$ can be characterized as the following Stratovich SDE: $$dX_t = P_i(X_t) \circ dW^i_t$$ where the Einstein summation convention is used.

I'm trying to understand a discrete approximation.  In particular, I want to compute and plot this representation on something simple (ex $S^2$), but because it's not in Ito form, using something like Euler Maruyama won't work.

I'm wondering, can I just blindly use the Stratovich SDE to Ito SDE formula (given on Wikipedia or in Oksendal) to convert this to an Ito SDE, and just perform Euler-Maruyama over $\mathbb{R}^n$ to approximate the process?  Or is there a subtlety about being on a manifold that I'm missing?  I've searched Google, the Arxiv, and Hsu's book for an Ito SDE that represents Brownian motion extrinsically for an embedded manifold.  Why can't I find it?  Did I not look hard enough, or is there something about manifolds that doesn't allow for an extrinsic Ito SDE description of Brownian motion?

Comment: In Hsu's book in Example 3.3.5, he gives Brownian motion in local coordinates.

Comment: Thank you very much!  I must have missed this.